# Efficient way to transform a dictionary into a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary such as :

```
  mydict=  {'scaffold1': SeqRecord(seq=Seq('AGAGGTAGAGGCAGAAAACATAGTGAGCACGCTGTGTTTAAT'), id='scaffold1', name='scaffold1', description='scaffold1 0.0', dbxrefs=[]), 'scaffold2': SeqRecord(seq=Seq('GCAAAAGCAAAGCCAGATCAGAGTCCAGACAGTGAAGGCAAGACTAGTAAAGT'), id='scaffold2', name='scaffold2', description='scaffold2 0.0', dbxrefs=[])}
```

I wondered if someone knew an efficient way to process this dictionary and create a dataframe from it by adding three columns:

- **Scaffolds** column which is the **keys** of the dictionary
- The **Seq_length** which is the length of the **Seq** string
- The **GC%** which is the number of `G` and `C` letters within Seq divided by the **Seq_length** (for example len(Seq) of **scaffold1** is **42**, and there are **18 G** and **C** letters (so `GC% = 18/42`)

I should then get :

```
Scaffolds Seq_length GC%
scaffold1 42         0.428 
scaffold2 53         0.453
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to do this task as my real dict is really huge (1,046,544 keys)

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: What is the structure of `Seq`? What are the available attributes on `Seq`?

Comment: I can get the Seq by using. :  ***mydict['scaffold1'].seq***, which gives me : 
Seq('AGAGGTAGAGGCAGAAAACATAGTGAGCACGCTGTGTTTAAT')

Comment: That's fine but how do you access the string value from `Seq('AGAGGTAGAGGCAGAAAACATAGTGAGCACGCTGTGTTTAAT')` is there any specific attribute?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma this is likely a biopython `Seq` object

Comment: mozway is correct, it is a biopython dictionary

Comment: @mozway I see. I'm not into biology but anyways it's good to know.

Comment: To get it as a string you van use : ***str(mydict['scaffold1'].seq)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rework the dictionary:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord

mydict = {'scaffold1': SeqRecord(seq=Seq('AGAGGTAGAGGCAGAAAACATAGTGAGCACGCTGTGTTTAAT'), id='scaffold1', name='scaffold1', description='scaffold1 0.0', dbxrefs=[]), 'scaffold2': SeqRecord(seq=Seq('GCAAAAGCAAAGCCAGATCAGAGTCCAGACAGTGAAGGCAAGACTAGTAAAGT'), id='scaffold2', name='scaffold2', description='scaffold2 0.0', dbxrefs=[])}

from Bio.SeqUtils import GC

df = pd.DataFrame([{'Scaffolds': k,
                    'Seq_length': len(s.seq),
                    'GC%': GC(s.seq)}
                   for k, s in mydict.items()])
```

output:

```
   Scaffolds  Seq_length        GC%
0  scaffold1          42  42.857143
1  scaffold2          53  45.283019
```

Comment: So much efficient than my loop ahah ! thansk a lot for your help :-)

Comment: biopython is not always very efficient, sometimes it's worth using a custom code ;)